# cannot navigate angular-ui boostrap typeahead with specific height with keyboard

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

So, I think it's more a bootsrap issue than angular-ui, but I spent 2 nights over this and I cannot find the light at the end of the tunnel.

Here's the plunkr :
http://plnkr.co/edit/n39LVjbHQzmcwGkk2dR1?p=preview

Search for "x" and then try to go down using the arrow keys. Items will be selected, but they will not gain focus.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? Please revert.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705490/up-down-arrow-key-issue-with-typeahead-control-angular-bootstrap-ui/32967199#32967199 for a possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution. I added another directive to the typeahead li element `shouldFocus` that watches for its active value to change. When it does it calls `scrollIntoView` on that element.

I guess this is considered a hack, but If typeahead allowed for dynamic templates, set from markup, then it would be a valid fix.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vzLHFqkHPUFCaaosVt5w?p=preview

Comment: This is not working when page having scroll and input element is little below.please help me to resolve this.