# How to add Up/down scroll for ngx-bootstrap typeahead?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I want the same functionality as in this answer, but the problem is , the answer is using ui-bootstrap and I am using ngx-bootstrap. How to achieve such functionality in ngx-bootstrap?

[up/down arrow key issue with typeahead control (angular bootstrap UI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705490/up-down-arrow-key-issue-with-typeahead-control-angular-bootstrap-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use ngx-bootstrap '3.0.0' and it works.
5 items in the list with scrollbar,
then cursor down serveral times, and the items scroll.
On the demo page (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead, at Scrollable you can also verify that it works as you want.